# Phoenix framework pattern match request headers

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, plug

I'm trying to implement a custom plug for API versioning. Now I need to be able to match a value passed with the requests headers (i.e. `Accept: application/vnd.app.v1+json`). So far I have implemented the following:

```
defmodule UsersApi.Plugs.APIVersion do
  import Plug.Conn

  @versions ["application/vnd.app.v1+json", "application/vnd.app.v2+json"]

  def init(version), do: version

  def call(%{req_headers: %{"accept" => version}} = conn, _) when version in @versions do
    assign(conn, :version, version)
  end

  def call(conn, version), do: assign(conn, :version, version)
end
```

This is not currently working and falling through to the second `call/2` which is designed as a fallback when no accept header is specified. How can I match with request headers?

Comment: `req_headers` is a list; you can't pattern match like this. You can use `get_req_header/2` though.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`req_headers` is a list but you're pattern matching it like a map, which always fails, and all calls to `call/2` end up in the fallback. You can use `get_req_header/2` for this:

```
def call(conn, default_version) do
  version = case get_req_header(conn, "accept") do
    [version] when version in @versions -> version
    _ -> default_version
  end
  assign(conn, :version, version)
end
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!!

Comment: How about pattern matching in a guard? This can't be done, can it?